# How can I simply count how many Multiprocesses are currently running in python?

Tags: python

My script runs a process called load, it takes more than 30 seconds to finish.
The connection to the proxy means that the processes take different amounts of time to complete each time they run.

I need my code to look like this

```
 while running == true:
     if not 25 multiprocesses running:
           start enough processes to reach 25 running
```

here's what my code looks like now, it just starts 10 processes and then ends as a test:

```
import random, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import multiprocessing

def load():
proxy = "falcon.proxyrotator.com:8080"
profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile.add_argument('headless')
profile.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxy)
profile.add_argument('--user-agent=' + UserAgent().random)                                    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=profile)
driver.get('https://ipchicken.com')
print ('done')
time.sleep(30)
driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
         time.sleep(7)
         print ('start')
         P = multiprocessing.Process(target=load)
         P.start()
```

Comment: At first you have to make a list of the processes you are spawning, then you query them for their state with `.is_alive()`.

Comment: I think it starts only 10 processed due to "for i in range(10)" loop which will run only 10 times. You need to implement logic here to check whether number of processes is less than 25 or not.